# form and view for nested attribute issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-attributes

I have checked the topics about how to create a nested attribute form, but can not get it work.

I have two models:

```
class LogFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ConfigFile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ConfigFile, allow_destroy: true
end

class ConfigFiles < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :LogFile
end
```

In the controller of the `logfile` I have:

```
 def log_file_params
      params.require(:log_file).permit(:name,
                                       ...,
                                       :config_file_id,
                                       config_files_attributes: [:id, :json, :_destroy])
 end
```

And the form looks like this:

```
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :config_file do |n| %>
      <%= n.input :json %>
  <% end %>
```

I need to populate the `config_file_id` field of the `log_file` model in order to be able to get the config file for particular log file.

I have try to change the `config_files_attributes` to `config_file_attributes`. Also, ti change the

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :config_file do |n| %>
```

to

```
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :config_file_attributes do |n| %>
 <%= f.simple_fields_for :config_files_attributes do |n| %>
```

but it seems I am not able to create a record in the `config_files` table (it is always empty).

Could anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

---

I have fix the camel case syntax and add a `log_file_id` column to `config_file` table.
I am yet not able to populate the `nested` table.

This is the `_form`:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :config_file_attributes do |n| %>
          <%= n.input :json %>
      <% end %>
```

This is the `controller`:

```
# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def log_file_params
      params.require(:log_file).permit(:name,
                                       :description,
                                       :log_file,
                                       :access_type_id,
                                       :config_file_id,
                                       config_file_attributes: [:id, :json, :_destroy])
    end
```

and here is the debug output (note that no information about the config_file is passed):

```
--- !ruby/object:LogFile
attributes:
  id: 2
  name: Tetsd2
  description: '123'
  created_at: 2014-09-04 09:34:48.141041000 Z
  updated_at: 2014-09-04 14:08:20.652419000 Z
  log_file: test.txt
  access_type_id: 2
  config_file_id:
```

Comment: Show your controller!!!

Comment: remove `config_file_id` in log_file_params method and please show full your controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a database conversion belongs_to should hold reference column so try add `log_id` in `ConfigFiles` table solve your issue. Rails also take value like so in nested attributes. I have tried it for `has_many` association.

Also You haven't specified has_one and belongs to in camel case. So correct that as well. Also in accept_nested_attributes_for.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed this but still not able to make it work. Could you  check the question edit?

Comment: Let me know if I need to provide other details.

Comment: Some more problem still there in code : like `<%= f.simple_fields_for :config_file do |n| %>
          <%= n.input :json %>
      <% end %>` No need of attributes here

Comment: Forget about this - everything is working ok. Thanks, a lot for pointing where I should create the reference column.

Answer (score 1):

Your symbols passed to association methods are wrong:

```
belongs_to :LogFile
```

This should be:

```
belongs_to :log_file
```

Notice the camel casing.

Likewise, the following is also wrong:

```
class LogFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :ConfigFile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ConfigFile, allow_destroy: true
end
```

And should be:

```
  has_one :config_file
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :config_file, allow_destroy: true
```

I think your `strong_parameters` call is wrong:

```
  params.require(:log_file).permit(:name,
    # ...
    config_files_attributes: []
```

Since a LogFile only has one ConfigFile, you should remove the `s`. It should be `config_file_attributes` and not `config_files_attributes`.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed this but still not able to make it work. Could you  check the question edit?